# Cant login with sandbox account in TestFlight

Tags: sandbox, testflight

I need to test purchases in the iOS app. The developer of the application created a sandbox account for me, I added this account in "Settings - App Stores - Sandbox account". Beforehand, I logged out of the App Store and iTunes accounts and logged out of the Apple ID.

Now when I try to log in to TetsFlight I get an error:

```
The Apple ID cannot be used with the itunes store at this time. Please try again later.
```

I'm out of ideas on how to fix this, maybe I'm doing something wrong?
If someone can, please provide the steps on how to properly log in to the sandbox account in TestFlight?